# TypeError : button is null but working fine in console

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I wanted to make a webpage in which on button click, the background color changes.

Its showing TypeError on loading in browser but its working fine after pasting same JavaScript on console.

---

**Code snippet**

```js
var colors = ["#0af5fa", "#0ab1fa", "#0a3efa", "#560afa", "#b70afa", "#fa0ad9", "#fa0a65", "#fa0a1e", "#fa5e0a", "#facc0a", "#cbfa0a", "#69fa0a", "#0afa1b", "#0afa77", "#0afae5", "#0a8efa"];

var flag = 0,
  blinkCount = 0;

function blink() {
  if (blinkCount == 15) {
    blinkCount = 0;
    blink();
  } else {
    var h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
    var body = document.querySelector("body");

    h1.style.color = colors[blinkCount];
    body.style.background = colors[blinkCount];
    blinkCount++;
  }
}

var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("click", blink);
```

```css
button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  margin-top: 300px;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

h1 {
  color: #0af5fa;
}

body {
  background: #0af5fa;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<script src="../JavaScript/ex153.js"></script>
<link href="../css/ex153.css" rel="stylesheet">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="">
    <button><h1>Click Me</h1></button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**In Browser [Error]**

```
TypeError: button is null[Learn More]     ex153.js:25:1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're running the script before the document has been fully parsed - see how the `<script>` is *above* the `<body>` and its `<button>`?

Either give the script tag the `defer` attribute:

```
<script defer src="..
```

Or move it to the bottom of the body:

```
    </div>
  <script src="../JavaScript/ex153.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or wrap the whole script in a DOMContentLoaded listener:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var colors;
    // other code
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I will read more about DOMContentLoaded.